# Django ASGI channels application not keeping track of multiple websocket clients (using redis and nginx)

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, redis, channel

### EDIT:

I had missed .as_asgi() when defining routes for my websockets, meaning each instance I created was overwritten by the next one I made.

My routing.py now looks like:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    url("calling/interface/", ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
                ]
            )
        )
    )
})
```

#### Origional Question:

I have Django with asgi channels hosted on a local vm, I am also using redis-channels and nginx. I am able to connect and use my application with one user however once creating a second connection, the old (original) client stops receiving web-socket information however it can still send it. My consumers.py receives all websocket data but thinks it's all from the newest connection. Meaning the the first ws connection does close but stops receiving information.

Versions:

```
Python = 3.9.2
Django = 3.1.7
Channels = 3.0.3
channels-redis = 3.2.0
redis = 5.0.3
```

I have been able to send websocket information from within consumers and outside for handling webhook responses, I just can't handle multiple connections on the consumer.

Nginx Configuration:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024; 
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    upstream websocket {
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;        

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://websocket;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Formwarded-Host $server_name;
        
        } # end location
    } # end server
} # end http
```

Consumers (cut down):

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.username = self.scope["session"]["tokenOwner"]

        await self.accept()
        await self.send(text_data="[Welcome %s!]" % self.username)
        token = self.scope["session"]["token"]
        webhook_response = await create_webhook()

        await create_record(webhook_response.id)

        print(f"New Channel: {self.channel_name}")
        print(f"Webhook ID: {webhook_response.id}")

    

    async def disconnect(self, message):
        token = self.scope["session"]["token"]
        closing_channel_name = self.channel_name

        WebhookID = await get_self_record()

        await asyncio.gather(delete_webhook(WebhookID))
        await delete_record()


    async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
    
        token = self.scope["session"]["token"]
    
        instructions = text_data.split("_")
        params = instructions[1:]
    
        #instructions are send as a string with data split by '_'
        #I handle the args sent and call a function based on them

    async def call_update(self, event):
       await self.send(text_data=event['text'])
```

Please let me know if you need any more information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had missed .as_asgi() when defining routes for my websockets, meaning each instance I created was overwritten by the next one I made.

My routing.py now looks like:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    url("calling/interface/", ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
                ]
            )
        )
    )
})
```